# Rails Quiz (find bugs in scope definition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following scope definition contains two bugs, which causes it not to work as expected. Can you find them?

```
named_scope :articles_to_display, 
            :conditions => ["articles.publish_at < (?)", Time.now]
```

(the column publish_at contains time/date, when the article should be published). The bugs are fundamental ones, not just a typos.

I will either accept the first correct answer or post the solution in few days.

Comment: Yes, rails 2.x, I am not familiar with Rails 3.x, but I would bet, that at least one of the problems will apply to them as well, more likely both.

Comment: so you know the correct answer? oO.

Comment: Yes, I know the correct answer. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure it belongs to SO site? :)

Comment: Is there a reason for the () around the placeholder?  I don't usually have them there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problems is that Time.now is evaluated at the class level (when the file is read by Ruby) and not evaluated when the scope is used (which is what you most likely expect). In that case you need to wrap the conditions generation in a lambda/proc.

```
named_scope :articles_to_display, lambda { 
   :conditions => ["articles.publish_at < (?)", Time.now]
}
```

The second issue is likely that you're want to use Time.zone.now instead of Time.now to respect the localized time of the current request rather than the system time on the server.

The following is what you want to end up with:

```
named_scope :articles_to_display, lambda { 
   :conditions => ["articles.publish_at < (?)", Time.zone.now]
}
```

Comment: I should have caught the lambda, as I use them all the time for dynamic parameters.  I didn't know about Time.zone, though.  My main project is an internal site that all takes place in one time zone. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
named_scope :articles_to_display, :conditions => ["articles.publish_at < (?)", DateTime.now]
```

Or try proc

```
named_scope :articles_to_display, proc{ :conditions => ["articles.publish_at < (?)", DateTime.now]}
```

*Here was a picture of a superman, that was deleted :D*

Answer (score 2):

For additional reference, the accepted answer, converted to rails 3, is:

```
scope :articles_to_display, lambda { 
      where("articles.publish_at < (?)", Time.zone.now)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
named_scope :articles_to_display, 
            :conditions => ["articles.publish_at IS NOT NULL AND articles.publish_at <= (?)", Time.now]
```

Comment: Quick try, nice. But the null value is not a problem (it just does not pass the condition). < vs. <= does not make much difference if we don't care about second precision.